# Encrypt a Zip File with Caesar Cipher

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to understand, why the Filesize of a Caesar Cipher encrypted foo.txt.zip File is smaller than a Caesar cipher encrypted foo.txt File.

For example:

Foo.txt size: 90bytes
foo.txt.Caesar.enc output File: 92bytes
(Here every character is shifted with the same size so the bytelength is nearly the same)

But why is:
The foo.txt.zip.Caesar.enc output file much smaller than the foo.txt.zip File ?
Is it because of another file format and no plain text like .txt ?

Comment: Maybe it is clear to you what these files actually contain, but I have a hard time understanding what you are asking. One file: text > cipher > zip and one text > zip > cipher?

Answer (score 1):

I guess because because foo.txt has a lot of redundancy and thus can be quite significantly compressed. Consequently, the compressed file foo.txt.zip is much smaller (you should take a look at data compression).